# Bulk Data extraction to DB File in C#

Tags: c#, sql, insert, mdf

I have Huge data say 45,00,000 rows of data in notepad file ,  
I split that gaint file into small files,

I have the data as follows:

```
('1','dsamp','tty','tmp'....)
and so on
```

Now i am reading the files one by one and using the insert script and a piece of C# code I am writing them to a .mdf file , but when i get some error I am unable to find where the error is and i want to start from beginning and insert from row 0.
Is there any best way or code or tool to do this
My code looks like this

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = 0;
        try
        {
            string const_state = "INSERT INTO Authors1 VALUES";
            string conn = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=c:\users\srikanth\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\SampleDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(conn);
            cn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = cn;
            string line;

            System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("C:\\Users\\Public\\New1.txt");
            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                line = line.Trim();
                line = line.TrimEnd(',', ',',',', '.');
                cmd.CommandText = const_state + line+";";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                i++;
            }
            MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());

            file.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }

    }
}
```

}

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you show us your code?  Sounds like you just need to rework your error handling to give you a better idea of the failures (i.e. which file contained the failed data, what the failure was, etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is having a `try/catch` block for your `ExecuteNonQuery()` call.  Something like this:

```
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            line = line.Trim();
            line = line.TrimEnd(',', ',',',', '.');
            cmd.CommandText = const_state + line+";";
            try 
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch
            {
                // dump cmd.CommandText somewhere as well as 
                // the actual exception details
                //
                // that'll give you two things: 1) the specific 
                // issue, and 2) the actual INSERT statement that 
                // failed
            }
            i++;
        }
```

*See my comments in the `catch { }` block on how I would handle an INSERT error*

By having the `try/catch` around the `ExecuteNonQuery()` call, you'll have the granular issue on *which* `INSERT` statement failed, as well as the particular exception with the error.  The other benefit to this is it would allow you to continue execution instead of bubbling that exception up to the outer `try/catch` logic.  Unless, of course, you want to stop execution, in which case you can just rethrow the exception from the inner `catch { }` block.  It all depends on how you want a failure handled.

***Note:  for your outer `try/catch` block, you should include a `finally { }` where you call `SqlConnection.Dispose()` to release the connection and dispose of the object (`cn.Dispose()`).***

Comment: Yah this should solve the issue with errors, what about time, for reading 45,00,000 rows will be a heavy weight work, is there a solution for that as well?

Comment: @SrikanthSuryadevara Are you referencing the duration to read the data out of the text files, *or* the duration of inserting the data into the database table?

Comment: Read from text files+write to DB